# Updating array of objects in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't handle updating array of objects in my database, tried many options but nothing worked. Im pretty sure that the answer is obvious, but I couldn't manage it since wednesday.
Here is my kitSchema:

```
const kitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  kit: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  profiles: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Kit", kitSchema);
```

All users have their own document, and there are also profiles in it. I want to update single profile by passing the id of user and id of profile.
Example of data:

```
_id: 1,
email: "abc@mail",
password: "abc",
profiles: [
           {
            id: 1,
            name: John
           },
          ]
```

And here's my latest solution which doesn't work:

```
router.put("/profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let kit = await Kit.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  try {
    await kit.profiles.findOneAndUpdate(
      { id: req.body.id },
      { name: req.body.name },
      { new: true },
      (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    );
    try {
      res.status(202).json({ message: "Changed" });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: err });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Could you give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1):

As always, after days of trying I've got answer 10 minutes after asking question. Here's what I came up with:

```
router.put("/profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  await Kit.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id, profiles: { $elemMatch: { id: req.body.id } } },
    {
      $set: {
        "profiles.$.name": req.body.name,
        "profiles.$.profilePicture": req.body.profilePicture,
      },
    },
    { new: true, safe: true, upsert: true },
    (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  );
  try {
    res.status(202).json({ message: "Changed" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
});
```